# No callbacks found for cron job Magento 2.3.5-p2

Tags: cron, magento2

We are using adyen Payment, since couple of months we started having an error on every 5-mins `"No callbacks found for cron job adyen_payment_process_notification_queue"`

[image]

Unfortunately we are not able to find the string having "adyen_payment_process_notification_queue" even in the vendor/adyen folder or in the app/code, can anyone guide us from where this could be coming from or what is the possibility for having such errors or how to find its resolutions.

Due to this error all our order status is being stuck in Processing  as shipment team tried to updated the status via cron but may be due to this error Order statuses are not updating.

We have also tried checking but there is no any clue related to this error. :

1. var/log/system.log
2. var/log/magento.cron.log
3. var/log/exception.log
4. var/log/adyen/cronjob.log
5. var/log/adyen/notification.log

Answer (score 1):

Try to search table "core_config_data" for not-uninstalled cron_expr configuration.

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%adyen_payment_process_notification_queue%'
```

Answer (score 0):

in your soruce patch you must put the group that will remain in your cron:
crontab.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="custom_group">
        <job name="custom_crome" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\YourClassCron" method="execute">
            <config_path>crontab/custom_group/jobs/your_cron/schedule/cron_expr</config_path>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

then your patch must be the same as your group it belongs to
<config_path>crontab/**custom_group**/jobs/your_cron/schedule/cron_expr</config_path>

Or in your model file where the cron takes the configurations you must put the name of the group to which the cron will belong:

```
const CRON_STRING_PATH = 'crontab/your_group_cron/jobs/your_cron/schedule/cron_expr';
const CRON_MODEL_PATH = 'crontab/your_group_cron/jobs/your_cron/run/model';
```